# How to 'push' to the branch after 'rebase', without 'force push' and without using another branch

Tags: git, github

**Situation:** small bug needs to be fixed, so you do not want to fork from the `master` and decide to fix it directly on master. You pull changes and start working on the fix, you finish, committed the change, and ready to push it to `master`, but while you where fixing, another devs pushed to the `master` branch, and now you are behind, pulling doesn't help. What you need it rebase. So you rebase your local `master` with `origin/master`. And now the only options known to me are:

1. Force push (not good at all when you work with other people on the branch).
2. Make your own branch at the beginning.

Is there 3d option? Without making the new branch and without force push?

1. Force push (not good at all when you work with other people on the branch).
2. Make your own branch at the beginning.

Comment: Third option is not rebasing and rather merging.

Comment: There's no way *not* to force push if you're rebasing. Rebasing deletes your previous commits and creates new ones. Merging will create a new commit on top of your existing commits.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If somebody has pushed to master and you haven't, then no force-push is needed after rebasing. If you have already pushed, then nobody else can push (without force-pushing themselves). Also, I don't get "pulling doesn't help" – if the local and remote branches have diverged, you have to merge them again (or rebase one onto the other). This question builds on wrong premises.

Comment: I agree with @knittl's false premise statement. You may have heard that one of the downsides of a rebase workflow is that you typically have to force push afterwards, but that's only true if you are updating a branch that has already been pushed. If you're pushing directly to a shared branch, then force push should never be allowed, and rebase is fine in your scenario with a regular push. It's just harder to do a code review without a separate branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rebase the *local* commits (ie the commits you have not yet push) on top of `origin/master`, then your next push will *not* be a forced one.

A regular `git push` would still work after your rebase.